# how to get current selected from <select> and on every change in selected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysqli

i was trying to make a dynamic  where the selected option was supposed to be caught in a variable for php as i would use it as a condition to be put in a where clause for mysql. and when a user selects another option the  of another  tag would change

```
<form method="GET" action="">
    <select name="docSpec" id="docSpec">

<?php   
    $docSpecQuery = "select DISTINCT specialty from doctors"; // i was going to put a where condition here so i could only project names of the doctor with the selected specialty.
    $docquery = "select doctorName from doctors";
    $docSpec = mysqli_query($conn,$docSpecQuery);
    $docresult = mysqli_query($conn,$docquery); 

    //this php block is for my options, i used a loop                                   
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($docSpec))
    {
        echo "<option value='$row[0]'>$row[0]</option>";
    }
    unset($row);
?>
    </select>                                   
    <script type="text/javascript">     
        $('#docSpec').on("change",function(){
            var option = $("option:selected",this).val();
            alert(option);
        }); 
    </script>
</form>
```

i hope i was clear enough i will be waiting if you want to clarify some things in my code.
tell me if you need another parts of my code. please i need help

Comment: Your jQuery code looks fine. You have not initialize <select id='docSpec'>

Comment: yeah i just added it. hmmmm it does look to be in right syntax but my alert is not showing. is there another way i can project the variable so i know the javascript is really working? thanks for the reply

Comment: You have written code on change event of select, so jQuery(this).val() will return selected option value

Comment: Add $(document).ready(function(){ // rest of your code });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PHP is executed on the server**, which means that by the time you print the `<select>` you run the jQuery code you can't affect the mysql query directly. You can however *move the query to another script*, and target it with an ajax call that returns the select and options or, ideally, the dataset so you can create it programmatically.

Your php script will do the same as it does right now but fetch the value from the url for the conditional query. For instance, you could have this php at `mysite.com/select.php` and pass the variable `gynecologist` like so `mysite.com/select.php?spec=gynecologist` then read it with `$_GET['spec']` and use it in the query.

In your javascript, you'll get that html by calling something like:

```
$('#docSpec').on("change",function(){
    $.get( "mysite.com/select.php?spec="+$(this).find("option:selected"), 
    function( data ) {
        //data contains the output for the php file, update the dom 
        //with it or whatever
    });
});
```

Comment: if i use php in with this. can i just drop the function(data){} part?

Comment: No, that function is what's called when we "get" the php file, the php file only contains the output of the select, not everything like right now. You'd have two files

Comment: i have a last question. do i have to enclose this with a function.ready() block????

Comment: A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready." jQuery detects this state of readiness for you, for instance using $(function(){ YOUR CODE });